# Fail metastore while insert to Hive table

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, hive-metastore

I'm using spark 3.1.0 and hive 3.1.2

I'm inserting data by spark, using dynamic partition mode:

```
df = spark.table("source_table")
df.write.format("orc").insertInto("target_table", overwrite=True)
```

table already has 10400 partitions
size of target table: 88 GB
count of rows 1303893000
hive schema:

```
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
|          col_name           |                     data_type                      | comment  |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
| col1                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col2                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col2                        | timestamp                                          |          |
| col3                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col3                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col4                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col5                        | decimal(18,2)                                      |          |
| col6                        | decimal(18,2)                                      |          |
| col7                        | string                                             |          |
| col8                        | string                                             |          |
| col9                        | bigint                                             |          |
| col10                       | decimal(18,2)                                      |          |
| col11                       | string                                             |          |
| col12                       | string                                             |          |
| col13                       | decimal(18,2)                                      |          |
| col14                       | string                                             |          |
| col15                       | string                                             |          |
| col16                       | string                                             |          |
| col17                       | string                                             |          |
| col18                       | bigint                                             |          |
| col19                       | string                                             |          |
| col20                       | string                                             |          |
| col21                       | string                                             |          |
| col22                       | string                                             |          |
| col23                       | bigint                                             |          |
| col24                       | timestamp                                          |          |
| col25                       | timestamp                                          |          |
| col26                       | string                                             |          |
| col27                       | string                                             |          |
| col28                       | timestamp                                          |          |
| col29                       | string                                             |          |
| download_ts                 | timestamp                                          |          |
| col30                       | string                                             |          |
| col31                       | string                                             |          |
| col32                       | string                                             |          |
| download_dt                 | date                                               |          |
| id1                         | bigint                                             |          |
| id2                         | bigint                                             |          |
| source_dt                   | date                                               |          |
| partitions                  | int                                                |          |
|                             | NULL                                               | NULL     |
| # Partition Information     | NULL                                               | NULL     |
| # col_name                  | data_type                                          | comment  |
| download_dt                 | date                                               |          |
| id1                         | bigint                                             |          |
| id2                         | bigint                                             |          |
| source_dt                   | date                                               |          |
| partitions_num              | int                                                |          |
+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+----------+
```

While inserting data i get an error:

```
AnalysisException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Transaction rolled back due to failure during commit)
```

i tried to check logs in yarn containers, check logs in spark-history, but I did not find any useful information, there are no errors in the logs

I tried to use msck repair table - didn't work
I tried to add parameter spark.mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2" to spark session - didn't working

Any ideas?
I will be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Upd:
Before insert i've copied files with hadoop distcp to target table and then i made msck repair table - it completed successfully, but insert to this table still failed with error of metastore. I think that the integrity of the data in the metastore is broken.

can this be fixed somehow?